# PostGIS - find circles a point is inside of

Tags: geolocation, postgis, geo

I have a game. Players are points and Items are circles with varying radii. Players can add Items. Players must also see Items they are in range of.

1. When an item is added, it is pretty straight-forward to find all Players within the range of an Item.
2. When a player moves, how do I find all the Items they can see?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why I was confused, the answer is of course:

ST_Within(geometry A , geometry B) where A is the circle and B the point.

So given a circle centered at coordinates (0, 5) with a radius of 50 and a point at (3, 7), the query would be:

```
ST_Within(
  ST_BUFFER(ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(0 5)'), 50),
  ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(3 7)'))
```

Comment: Use [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) instead of ST_Within + ST_Buffer: `ST_DWithin(ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(0 5)'), ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(3 7)'), 50)`